# advice handler on aws outbound channel adapter

Tags: amazon-s3, spring-integration, spring-cloud

In the past I have been able to apply advice chain handlers on different outbound channel adapters. I am trying to do the same on `int-aws:s3-outbound-channel-adapter` but its not allowing that. Does this component not allows this behavior. Basically I am interested in finding out when the adapter completes the upload of a file to S3.

```
<int-aws:s3-outbound-channel-adapter
    id="s3-outbound" channel="files" bucket="${s3.bucket}"
    multipart-upload-threshold="5192" remote-directory="${s3.remote.dir}"
    accessKey="${accessKey}" secretKey="${secretKey}">

    THIS DOESNT WORKS - throws an error !!!
    <int:request-handler-advice-chain>
    </int:request-handler-advice-chain> 

</int-aws:s3-outbound-channel-adapter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, that isn't allowed by the XSD. Feel free to raise a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INTEXT) on the matter.

But that doesn't matter that it doesn't work at all.

If you are on Spring Integration 4.x already you can move that `<int-aws:s3-outbound-channel-adapter>` to the Java & Annotation configuration using `@Bean` and `@ServiceActivator` for the `AmazonS3MessageHandler`.

Where `@ServiceActivator` has `adviceChain` attribute to specify bean references to your `Advice`s.

... or you can do that using generic `<int:outbound-channel-adapter>` and specify `AmazonS3MessageHandler` as raw `<bean>` for the `ref` of the first one.
HTH